# set margin between Drawer icon and title

Tags: java, android, styles, drawerlayout, persian

I'm creating a persian app and this is my DrawerLayout but there is too much space between the Drawer icons and titles how can i decrease it ?

[image]
I've tried to use a custom Style but i didn't worked

By the way i used this code to make the app RTL

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void ForceRTLIfSupported(){
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
     getWindow().getDecorView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}}
```

layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
layout="@layout/appbar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
app:headerLayout="@layout/main_nav_header"       app:menu="@menu/main_activity_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you add your layout code

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of your navigation view in a way like this.

In the margin Bottom, change the values.

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
</style>
```

layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/appbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/main_nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/main_activity_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```